# How can I make a paint animation that covers an object?

Tags: animation, node-editor, texture-painting

I'm trying to make an animation in which a color covers an object.

The thing is, I don't want the color to appear over the entire object at once, but rather start from an edge and slowly move across its face.

The closest result I've managed to achieve was by using a Gradient node, but the effect isn't very good.

Are there other ways to achieve this effect?

Comment: What do you not like about the gradient approach?

Comment: Have you looked into Dynamic Paint? You can use a variety of methods there to simulate an actual paint brush if you want.